# How to merge two Hashmaps and sum the values for the same keys?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have an object (`EnergyUsageData`) which presents the energy usage for each energy type which has two fields:

```
private EnergyType type;
private Map<YearMonth, BigDecimal> billsMap;
```

The map contains the energy bills data.
I am getting the energy bills data and putting them in a list:

```
List<EnergyUsageData> energyUsageDataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to combine the maps for those with the same energy type. For example if I have more than one element in the list for Diesel energy type I want to combine the `billsMap` for them and add the energy usages for the same `YearMonth`. I am looking for an efficient way to combine the data and generating a list which has just one element for each energy type. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not making much sense to me.  For a start, you *cannot* have a `HashMap` with duplicate keys.  Perhaps you need a `MultiMap`

Comment: You seem to use list and map interchangeably, which makes it very confusing trying to determine what you're asking. Please provide some example input and your desired output, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Stephen the HashMap does not have duplicate keys. I just want to combine the maps for same energy types inside the list or before I putting them in the list. (each element inside the list have a type with a map of energy usages).

Comment: @Nisman - your question title says: *"How to sum up the values when there are duplicate keys in a Hashmap?"*.  Why do you ask that if there are NOT duplicate keys in the hashmap?  Your question still makes no sense.

Comment: What you can do is HashMap<key, HashSet<value>> and have one key associated with multiple values? But there is no way of actually having more than one of the same key in a map.

Comment: @Stephen sorry for any confusion. I just want to combine two maps in a way that the values for the same keys get summed up.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
For all keys in table 2
  v2 = that key's value in table 2.
  v1 = that key's value in table 1.
  If v1 is null
    Set key and v2 pair into table 1.
  Otherwise
    Sum the two values
    Set key and sum pair in table 1.
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 streams you can do it efficiently like this.

```
public static List<EnergyUsageData> process(final Collection<EnergyUsageData> data) {
    final Map<EnergyType, Map<YearMonth, BigDecimal>> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    final List<EnergyUsageData> energyUsageData = data.stream()
            .flatMap(d -> d.getBillsMap().entrySet().stream().map(
                    dd -> new FlatData(d.getType(), dd.getKey(), dd.getValue())))
            .filter(d -> {
                final Map<YearMonth, BigDecimal> map = tempMap.get(d.type);
                if (map != null) {
                    final BigDecimal amount = map.get(d.yearMonth);
                    map.put(d.yearMonth, amount.add(d.amount));
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            .map(d -> {
                final HashMap<YearMonth, BigDecimal> billsMap = new HashMap<>();
                billsMap.put(d.yearMonth, d.amount);
                tempMap.put(d.type, billsMap);
                return new EnergyUsageData(d.type, billsMap);
                //Assuming Constructor of EnergyUsageData will hold
                // the reference of billsMap and will not copy billsMap
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return energyUsageData;
}

final class FlatData {
    public final EnergyType type;
    public final YearMonth yearMonth;
    public final BigDecimal amount;

    FlatData(EnergyType type, YearMonth yearMonth, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.type = type;
        this.yearMonth = yearMonth;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

It will process value one by one and loop over the entire collection exactly once.